# How to rescue a parachain from "Could not find header of the genesis block in the database" error?

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template

I have a situation where I uploaded the genesis wasm and state to the relay chain network, and then proceeded to make a few changes to the parachain node after that and compile it. When I ran the new parachain node I was greeted with :

```
Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database! block_hash=0xb2..1e
```

Instead of trying to purge and restart my relay chain network (which already has paraID 2000 registered), I am trying to salvage the situation for educational reasons.

For this I did the following:

1. Regenerate raw chain spec for the parachain, purge the old parachain database, run the parachain with new chain spec.
2. export the genesis-wasm and genesis-state for this parachain and upload it to the relay chain with a sudo call to `paras.forceSetCurrentCode(2000, newCode)` and `paras.forceSetCurrentHead(2000, newHead)`.
3. Restart parachain node.

The error still persists and my parachain refuses to build new blocks.

Comment: Did you offboard your parachain first? sudo sub-page, pick parasSudoWrapper > sudoScheduleParaCleanup

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas I did not (didn't know about this). Will try out this solution thanks.

Comment: did it resolve the issue?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas I had forgotten about this. I tried to reproduce this error, but this time I wasn't able to produce that error, I think I am missing something, so I cannot verify that sudoScheduleParaCleanup would've been the correct solution.